# How to check if a class has overridden equals and hashCode

Tags: java

Is there a way to find out if a class has overriden `equals()` and `hashCode()` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use reflection

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method method = Bar.class.getMethod("hashCode" /*, new Class<?>[] {...} */); // pass parameter types as needed
    System.out.println(method);
    System.out.println(overridesMethod(method, Bar.class));
}

public static boolean overridesMethod(Method method, Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz == method.getDeclaringClass();
}

class Bar {
    /*
     * @Override public int hashCode() { return 0; }
     */
}
```

will print `false` if the `hashCode()` is commented out and `true` if it isn't.

[`Method#getDeclaringClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) will return the `Class` object for the class where it is implemented.

**Note** that [`Class#getMethod(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) works for `public` methods only. But in this case, `equals()` and `hashCode()` must be `public`. The algorithm would need to change for other methods, depending.

Comment: Important note: I didn't realize this until I looked it up, but `getMethod("hashCode")` doesn't simply return a method named `hashCode`; it returns a method named `hashCode` **with no parameters**.  `getMethod` takes a varargs list of `Class<?>` parameters that must match the method's parameters, and if there are no such parameters, it only matches methods with zero parameters.  That isn't obvious from the code above, and I thought it was flawed (if the class declares a `hashCode` with parameters) until I looked it up.

Comment: Refinement: The OP didn't say what should happen if class `A` overrides `equals` and `hashCode`, and class `B` extends `A` but doesn't override them.  If the desired result is still `true` (since it's not using the `Object` defaults), change `clazz == method.getDeclaringClass()` to `Object.class != method.getDeclaringClass()`.  [But I haven't tested.]

Comment: @ajb For your refinement, that would be the way to do it. In that case, there would be no need to pass the target `Class`.

Comment: I have problems getting your code to work for `equals`, I get a `NoSuchMethodException` ...is there another way to test for overridden equals?

Comment: it's runnable at [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/deF)  , I get the same problem with other code in my project based on this answer as well.. hashCode works fine. I have java 8

Comment: @ycomp `equals` has a single parameter of type `Object`. You need to mention that when you use `getMethod`. So `getMethod("equals", Object.class)`.

Answer (score 2):

to check if a method is declared in your class you can use the following code.

```
System.out.println(C.getMethod("yourMethod").getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName());
```

here you can find the name of the declaring class.

So check using the code in your subclass to check if equals or hasCode  method. And match if the declaring class name is same as your desired class

Comment: I'd prefer to use `==` on the class, rather than trying to match the name, just in case someone with a perverse sense of humor names a nested or inner class `Object`.