# Require a generic type to not use Object class's default equals and hashCode methods

Tags: java

Let's say I have some class

```
public class SomeClass<T> {
    public SomeClass() {
        //or throw exception here if T is not an interface but this is not preferred.
    }
}
```

Can I somehow require `T` to have `equals` and `hashCode` overriden `Object`'s implementations? One way I can think of is using something like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass.GoodClass> {
    public static abstract class GoodClass {
        protected abstract boolean equalsImpl(Object other);

        @Override
        public final boolean equals(Object other){
            return equalsImpl( other );
        }
    } 
}
```

But I do want to use the abstract class approach since I cannot use any classes which extend some other class (no multiple inheritence, and using a wrapper just adds even more boiler plate).

For the exception route maybe I can use something from 
[How to check if a class has overridden equals and hashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031489/how-to-check-if-a-class-has-overridden-equals-and-hashcode)
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974262/5130921.

Comment: There is no way to require a generic type that overrides Object's `hashCode` and `equals()`. After type erasure, generics are `java.lang.Object` anyway.